# Angular undefined error while running ng test with environment.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test

I have environment.ts in project to set env data from kubernate yaml.

```
export const environment = {
  PROD_URL: window["env"].prodUrl || 'http://localhost:8080/v1/'
};
```

While running ng test , I am getting below error.

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prodUrl ' of undefined
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prodUrl ' of undefined
      at Module.AytR (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/environments/environment.ts:9:30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window["env"]` can be `null`/`undefined`. For that case just use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).

```
export const environment = {
  PROD_URL: window["env"]?.prodUrl || 'http://localhost:8080/v1/'
};
```